# Binding when assigning value in ViewModel does not work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In the View I have a stacklayout which I assign the IsVisible property which has a Binding. This Binding I assign the value in the ViewModel but when assigning the value in the ViewModel, nothing happens.

The View and the ViewModel are correctly connected because other Binding works correctly but this one does not.

**MainPage.xaml:**

```html
 <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView>
                            <Frame>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Image />
                                            <Image />
                                            <Label />
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <ImageButton />
                                                    <ImageButton />
                                                </Grid>
                                                <ImageButton
                                                    IsVisible="{Binding stackVisible}"
                                                    Source="img1"
                                                    WidthRequest="25" />
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label />
                                            <Label />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

This is an example of my XAML, the `ImageButton` with the `IsVisible` property that I want to modify is inside many tags, I don't know if that is the reason why it doesn't work correctly.

**ViewModel:**

```
    private bool _stackVisible;
    public bool stackVisible
    {
        get => _stackVisible;
        set
        {
            _stackVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewModel() {
        stackVisible = false;
    }
```

Comment: I updated my post. I have updated the XAML code, now it is very similar to the one I have. The `ImageButton` tag that I want to change the value of `IsVisible` to with a Binding is inside many other tags.

Comment: What could be the problem? I am not able to fix it

Comment: You code seems has no issue . So you could share a sample so that I can test it on my side .